Entry denied into South Africa
I was denied entry into South Africa, "admission applied for" was written on my passport. Will that have any effect if I want to apply for a Schengen or a US visa?

For completeness, why were you denied entry? What is your citizenship? Have you had a Schengen or US visa previously?

Why were you denied entry? Generally, previous denials may create prejudice.
